# How to pass response body field to other request's body (Gatling)

Tags: scala, testing, simulation, load-testing, gatling

I have two end point.

**-/authenticate**

**-/authenticate/verification**

**/authenticate** return guid field on response body.
and **/authenticate/verification** requires that field  on request body.

I have tried to get guid like this :

`jsonPath("$..guid").saveAs("verificationGuid")`

and pass it to other body :

`.body(StringBody(s"{\"guid\":${verificationGuid}, \"code\":\"123456\"}"))`

this is the code block:

```
 def login = {
    exec(http("Authenticate")
      .post("/authenticate")
      .body(StringBody(userString))
      .headers(headerLogin)
      .check(status is 200)
      .check(jsonPath("$..guid").saveAs("verificationGuid"))
    )
    .exec(http( "Authenticate verify")
    .post("/authenticate/verify")
    .headers(headerLogin)
    .body(StringBody(s"{\"guid\":${verificationGuid}, \"code\":\"123456\"}"))
    .check(status is 200)
    )
  }
```

But it doesnt work, how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `s` from `s"{\"guid\":${verificationGuid}, \"code\":\"123456\"}")`. If `s` is in front of string every `${something}` placeholder will be treated as Scala built in string interpolation and compiler will try to replace it with Scala variable, which in your case does not exist. Without `s` it will be treated as literal string and than caught  by Gatling EL Parser and replaced with previously saved Gatling session attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by using [FasterXML Jackson Module](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-kotlin) in my Kotlin application. For Scala, you can use [same module for Scala](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.module/jackson-module-scala) as well.

For my Kotlin project, I added Jackson module in the pom.xml:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-kotlin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

My Kotlin code for my simulation class is like below:

```kotlin
    private val url: String = "<URL-STRING>" // Put a URL string here to send request
    private val yourObject = <YOUR-OBJECT> // Create your object here
    private val objectAsJson: String = ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(yourObject)
    private val requestBody: Body = StringBody(objectAsJson)

    private val scn = scenario("Post Request Simulation")
        .exec (
            http("Post Request")
                .post(url)
                .body(requestBody)
                .asJson()
                .check(status().`is`(HTTP_OK))
            )
```

I used `writeValueAsString` method to convert my Kotlin object into JSON object. Then I converted this JSON object into StringBody object to be able to process the object as a request body using Gatling.